# Best approach to develop app to find nearby places at your destination

Tags: objective-c, ios, geolocation, geocoding

I am trying to create an app that will help to find nearby places (e.g. atm, petrol station). These nearby places will also display additional information (for example, does the petrol station has car wash etc) I was thinking of the following approach:

1. Consolidate the list of places (e.g. petrol station) and additional information (e.g. Whether it has car wash facilities etc) using Core Data
2. Using the address of the list of places, find the coordinates (longtitude/latitude) and store in core data as well (can i use revers geo-coding here?)
3. Either with user's current location or custom location, the app will search the database and find the list of places which are closest to the indicated location.

Can you advise if there is a more effective way of approaching this sort of app?

Comment: I am interested in IOS platform. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the FourSquares api in light of the fact it is easy to implement:
http://groups.google.com/group/foursquare-api/web/api-documentation

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey thanks! Just a quick question, will I be able to find facilities like petrol stations, carparks etc using fourSquare API? From my limited knowledge on fourSquare, it seems to focus more on places like coffee places, resturarants etc

Comment: You're right, when I used foursquares few times I found my hands tied to limitation but believe me unless your client is paying you a lot of money and you have lot of time, this is the best to go.

The other option is to make your own database for these locations just like the one done by the Facebook in its android and iPhone app.

Comment: @Guru, is it feasible to use core data alone?

Comment: Frankly speaking it depends!
If your users would be looking for only a limited locations such as a group of schools, patrol pumps etc. then go for core data solution but what if your users want to search the schools in any location, in this case you need an API so that you can have access to vast amount of data!